# print rows that match exact pattern using awk

Tags: regex, awk, grep, pattern-matching

I have a file with names, and I want to search for them in a huge tab delimited file and get the corresponding rows. I need to match the exact names. So I tried this grep option, where I search a big file using a the names file (-f) , and I specify that I want **exact matches (-w).**

```
grep -f names -w bigfile > outputfile
```

Because tab delimited file is quite big, the grep command takes too long, so I am looking for an awk alternative. So far I tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0}NR>FNR{if($2==a[$2])print $0}' names bigfile > outputfile
```

Here, I look for matches in column 2 of the big file and print the corresponding rows.

The problem is that this awk option is not specific. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to modify this one-liner so that it matches exact regular expressions?

EDIT

Here's an example:

let's say that the names file looks like this:

```
GN2a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.309117_1
GN4a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.303417_1
GN3a__NODE_1000343_length_1013_cov_0.309417_2
GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_1
GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_10
GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_8
GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_83
```

and the first 9 rows of a tab delimited bigfile that has > 8 million rows looks like this:

```
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1232:2187#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.309117_1      
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN4a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.303417_1  
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN3a__NODE_1000343_length_1013_cov_0.309417_2
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_1
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_10
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_14
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_8
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_83
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_87
```

i would like my output to look like this:

```
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1232:2187#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.309117_1     
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN4a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.303417_1  
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN3a__NODE_1000343_length_1013_cov_0.309417_2
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_1
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_10
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_8
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_83
```

And instead with the awk one-liner, I get:

```
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1232:2187#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.309117_1      
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN4a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.303417_1  
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN3a__NODE_1000343_length_1013_cov_0.309417_2
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_1
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_10
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_8
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_83
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_87
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for showing your efforts in form of code, keep it up. Could you please post small/sensible sample data set of input and expected output too in your question so that we will get more understanding on it, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Also by seeing your attempt looks like you are dealing with 2 Input_file(s) so kindly do post small snippet of samples of both of them along with expected sample output too in your question.

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Since OP's samples were completely changed so adding this solution now, again based on shown samples only.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/[[:alnum:]]+__NODE_[0-9]+_length.*cov_[0-9]+\.[0-9]+_[0-9]+/) && (substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a)
' names Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested on shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/Gene[0-9]+/) && (substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a)
' names Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  a[$0]                                 ##Creating array a with index of current line here.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statement from here.
}
match($0,/Gene[0-9]+/) && (substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) in a)    ##Matching regex of Gene digits(which are coing together) AND making sure this substring(which is actually matched value by regex) is present in names file array then print current line.
' names  Input_file                     ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That would probably work, but my 'names' file is more complex than just "Gene". I realized that I should have probably mentioned that before. I edited the post.

Comment: @joanaseneca, its completely changed now :) lemme edit solution now in few mins and get back :)

Comment: @joanaseneca, Could you please check EDIT solution and lemme know how it goes please?

Comment: alright!! this works!! :D I will now upscale! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your one-liner though it could be simplified to this for a slight performance gain

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]} NR>FNR{if($2 in a)print $0}' names bigfile >outputfile
```

or bit more compact

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]} NR>FNR && $2 in a' names bigfile >outputfile
```

My guess is there are invisible control characters in your names file that are throwing off the output

I'm also surprised you found grep slower than awk. My tests with your data duplicated to 3 million lines show grep is 3x faster than awk

Are you running this on Linux? Is this GNU grep and awk?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply! Yes, for both your questions :) I realized that it only got slower when I added the -w option on grep. There was a lot of trial and error involved. I actually made up this dummy dataset based on the error that I identified before. I ran the code and it works for this dummy dataset so I'm embarrassed to even have asked the question with using this data. I mostly just wanted to ask for an awk -w equivalent, as it exists for grep

Comment: ok - this should not happen with basic matching - grep should be much much faster than awk

Comment: `NR==FNR{a[$0]} NR>FNR{if($2 in a)print $0}` is more commonly/idiomatically written as `NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $2 in a`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62521989/1745001.

Answer (score 2):

your explanation is not very clear.  It seems like you're trying for an exact literal match, not regex.

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' names bigfile > outputfile
```

should work even if you have spaces in the first field.  However, I expect a literal grep match to be faster than this.

Note that this is almost the same as the other `awk` script.

Answer (score 1):

This is the job that `join` exists to do:

```
$ join -t$'\t' -1 1 -2 2 -o '2.1 2.2' <(sort names) <(sort -k2,2 bigfile)
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1232:2187#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.309117_1
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_1
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN2a__NODE_1020349_length_1013_cov_0.109437_10
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN3a__NODE_1000343_length_1013_cov_0.309417_2
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GN4a__NODE_1000349_length_1013_cov_0.303417_1
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_8
7001253F:563:CC1HJANXX:8:2210:1968:2031#CTGAAGCTCAGGACGT    GO4a__NODE_9_length_201043_cov_2.340371_83
```